# cant align button in button group to the top in MVC

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I am having great difficulty moving the text in the button on the left hand side to the top(Risk Level 3).  Its a web application in MVC and i am using button groups in bootstrap. I've tried vertical-align and top:0. but still had no luck.

I have tried numerous things when inspecting element but had no luck.  The span tag seems to be full width in the other two buttons.  but the span tag in the far left button only seems to be the width of the text.

[image]

Code:

```
 @foreach (GRATT.DTO.ClinicalAreas ca in Model.ClinicalAreasList)
                    {
                        <div class="btn-group col-lg-4" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                            <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar"  style="width:100%" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
                                <button type="button" id="btnClinical" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="GetId(this)">
                                    <h4>Risk Level: @ca.ClinicaLevel</h4>
                                    <span>@ca.ClinicalDescription</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Please post your rendered HTML and CSS. As the question stands, we have no place to really start and help. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this, The below is a **css flex-box solution**,
since an id selector is there for button, I had used that to style the button.

```
#btnClinical {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on.  Thankyou.  The only css i was using is bootstraps.